# Is there a built-in way to detect wheter a user changed the default value of an option in docopt?

Tags: python-2.7, command-line-arguments, docopt

Suppose one has the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Does something.

Usage: 
   myprog.py --myopt=<myval>

Options:
  --myopt=<myval>  Some option [default: bla]
"""

arguments = docopt(__doc__)
print arguments
```

**Is there a way to check whether the user gave a value for the option '--myopt', or left the default value unchanged?**

I'd hate to repeat the default value in an if-statement like this:

```
if arguments['--myopt'] != 'bla':
```

or use a regex on `__doc__` to extract the default value from the docstring. After all, `docopt` already did parse the docstring.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? This would print the doc help if the --myopt argument was not used or had a blank entry.

`if arguments['--myopt'] is None:
        print __doc__
        exit(0)`